# Trait implementing Sized

Tags: rust

I know that traits and slices are unsized, i.e. it's not possible to know their size at compile time, e.g. any type may implement a trait, but that type may not be sized.

Nevertheless, doesn't this example code mean that every type which implements trait `Foo` needs to implement `Sized` too?

```
trait Foo: Sized {}

struct Bar(i64);

impl Foo for Bar {}
```

If that's so, why doesn't this work?

```
impl From<Foo> for Bar {
    fn from(foo: Foo) -> Bar {
        Bar(64)
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:7:6
  |
7 | impl From<Foo> for Bar {
  |      ^^^^^^^^^ `Foo + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `Foo + 'static`
```

I want to provide to the consumer of the library a type (let's name it `Bar`) and make it possible to convert to `Bar` from any other type which implements a particular trait (let's name it `Foo`).

I solved it by passing `Foo` by the reference instead of the value, but I'm not sure why the compiler complains if it's required for implementors to be `Sized`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Why doesn't it work?

When you say that every `Foo` is `Sized`, you're kind of hiding the truth to yourself. Yes, every `Foo` is `Sized` but actually every type has a given size at some point. The real important information is that you're not saying how much this size is. Imagine if `Bar(i64)` is `Foo`, but `Baz(i8)` is `Foo` as well (they're both `Sized`, right?) which size do you determine `Foo` to be? Is it 8- or 1-byte long? This question is asked by the compiler when it tries to generate the code for your function `from(foo: Foo)`. Usually, `Sized` is rather used in a "maybe"-style with the syntax `?Sized`, indicating that the type size might be unknown at compile time.

## How to solve it?

Typically you ditch the `: Sized` part, and use the following syntax, which is actually kind of a C++ template; it gives the compiler a sketch to write the actual code when given a concrete type with a given size.

```
trait Foo {}

struct Bar(i64);

impl Foo for Bar {}

impl<F: Foo> From<F> for Bar {
    fn from(foo: F) -> Bar {
        Bar(64)
    }
}
```

(This will [still error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a9cf828810457167da111d14695c26d5&version=stable) based on [the fact that you cannot reimplement `From` because of the `std` crate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423), but it's not related to your original question.)

You could also use the reference trait object `&Foo` syntax in the argument to your function. This would transform your call from static dispatch to dynamic dispatch ([read more here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta/book/static-and-dynamic-dispatch.html)) but you can't do this here because the signature is imposed by the trait.

Answer (score -1):

The `Foo` trait requires implementors to be `Sized`. It doesn't mean that `Foo` itself will have a size. You're misunderstanding the syntax the second code example and I'm therefore not sure what you're actually trying to do. Are you looking for this?

```
impl From<i64> for Bar {
    fn from(val: i64) -> Bar {
        Bar(val)
    }
}
```

Or do you want a way to construct a `Bar` from any signed integer?

We've got a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.