# How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement an error enum which can contain an error associated with one of our traits like this:

```
trait Storage {
    type Error;
}

enum MyError<S: Storage> {
    StorageProblem(S::Error),
}
```

I have also tried to implement the `From` trait to allow construction of `MyError` from an instance of a `Storage::Error`:

```
impl<S: Storage> From<S::Error> for MyError<S> {
    fn from(error: S::Error) -> MyError<S> {
        MyError::StorageProblem(error)
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=30ff7a5205117f0a22c58b965609bd95&version=stable))

However this fails to compile:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<MyError<_>>` for type `MyError<_>`:
 --> src/lib.rs:9:1
  |
9 | impl<S: Storage> From<S::Error> for MyError<S> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T> std::convert::From<T> for T;
```

I don't understand why the compiler reckons this has already been implemented.  The error message is telling me that there's already an implementation of `From<MyError<_>>` (which there is), but I'm not trying to implement that here - I'm trying to implement `From<S::Error>` and `MyError` is not the same type as `S::Error` from what I can see.

Am I missing something fundamental to generics here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem here is someone may implement `Storage` so that the `From` impl you have written overlaps with the impl in the standard library of `impl<T> From<T> for T` (that is, anything can be converted to itself).

Specifically,

```
struct Tricky;

impl Storage for Tricky {
    type Error = MyError<Tricky>;
}
```

(The set-up here means this doesn't actually compile—`MyError<Tricky>` is infinitely large—but that error is unrelated to the reasoning about `impl`s/coherence/overlap, and indeed small changes to `MyError` can make it compile without changing the fundamental problem, e.g. adding a `Box` like `StorageProblem(Box<S::Error>),`.)

If we substitute `Tricky` in place of `S` in your impl, we get:

```
impl From<MyError<Tricky>> for MyError<Tricky> {
    ...
}
```

This `impl` exactly matches the self-conversion one with `T` == `MyError<Tricky>`, and hence the compiler wouldn't know which one to choose. Instead of making an arbitrary/random choice, the Rust compiler avoids situations like this, and thus the original code must be rejected due to this risk.

This coherence restriction can definitely be annoying, and is one of reasons that [specialisation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) is a much-anticipated feature: essentially allows manually instructing the compiler how to handle overlap... at least, [one of the extensions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md#the-lattice-rule) to the current restricted form allows that.

Comment: Has the extension been implemented in nightly now?

Comment: No, and in fact the restricted form is still available only in nightly. I believe the intention is to let that bake for a bit/iron out the bugs before diving into the more flexible/powerful versions.

Comment: A clear answer: thanks.  I guess the error message could be a bit clearer if it said something like there *could be* conflicting implementations rather than implying there already are.

Comment: @Fraser, yeah, definitely, I guess it may be covered by https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23980 (I'll write a comment summarising this particular piece of confusion there).

Comment: I think it would work if you could specify that U != T. Maybe it is a naive reasonment, but I don't see why it's not a feature from the language

Answer (score 14):

A workaround for the coherence issue is to use some other method or trait.

In the specific posted example involving `Result`s, you can use [`Result::map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) to perform the conversion yourself. You can then use the transformed `Result`  with `?`:

```rust
fn example<S: Storage>(s: S) -> Result<i32, MyError<S>> {
    s.do_a_thing().map_err(MyError::StorageProblem)?;
    Ok(42)
}
```

This solution is also valuable when there are error variants that have the same underlying `Error`, such as if you want to separate "file opening" and "file reading" errors, both of which are `io::Error`.

In other cases, you might need to create a brand new method on your type or an alternate trait:

```rust
struct Wrapper<T>(T);

// Instead of this
//
// impl<T, U> From<Wrapper<T>> for Wrapper<U>
// where
//     T: Into<U>,
// {
//     fn from(other: Wrapper<T>) -> Self {
//         Wrapper(other.0.into())
//     }
// }

// Use an inherent method

impl<T> Wrapper<T> {
    fn from_another<U>(other: Wrapper<U>) -> Self
    where
        U: Into<T>,
    {
        Wrapper(other.0.into())
    }
}

// Or create your own trait

trait MyFrom<T> {
    fn my_from(other: T) -> Self;
}

impl<T, U> MyFrom<Wrapper<T>> for Wrapper<U>
where
    T: Into<U>,
{
    fn my_from(other: Wrapper<T>) -> Self {
        Wrapper(other.0.into())
    }
}
```