# If I implement From<A> for B, will From<Vec<A>> for Vec<B> also be implemented?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

It seems like no, because I have code that implements `From<A> for <B>`, and I can convert an `A` to a `B` with `.into()`, but the same thing isn't working for a `Vec<A>` `.into()` a `Vec<B>`.

Either I've screwed up something that's preventing the implementation from being derived, or this isn't supposed to happen.

If it's not supposed to work, why not? It seems like code such as this would work:

```
impl<A: From<B>, B> From<Vec<A>> for Vec<B> {
    // ... map .into onto vec of As to vec of Bs ...
}
```

I'm guessing there's more complexity to it than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to guess at which implementations of `From` exist for `Vec`; they are [all listed in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-From<Box<[T]>>). The list as of Rust 1.21.0:

```
impl<'a, T> From<&'a mut [T]> for Vec<T> { /**/ }

impl<T> From<BinaryHeap<T>> for Vec<T> { /**/ }

impl<T> From<VecDeque<T>> for Vec<T> { /**/ }

impl<'a, T> From<&'a [T]> for Vec<T>  { /**/ }

impl From<String> for Vec<u8> { /**/ }

impl<'a, T> From<Cow<'a, [T]>> for Vec<T> { /**/ } 

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Vec<u8> { /**/ }

impl<T> From<Box<[T]>> for Vec<T> { /**/ }
```

Instead, you will want to do something like:

```
let b: Vec<Wrapper> = a.into_iter().map(Into::into).collect();
```

---

If you tried to implement this, you'd get a failure:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `core::convert::From<vec::Vec<_>>` for type `vec::Vec<_>`:
    --> /Users/shep/Projects/rust/src/liballoc/vec.rs:2190:1
     |
2190 | / impl<A, B> From<Vec<A>> for Vec<B>
2191 | |     where A: Into<B>
2192 | | {
2193 | |     fn from(s: Vec<A>) -> Vec<B> {
2194 | |         s.into_iter().map(Into::into).collect()
2195 | |     }
2196 | | }
     | |_^
     |
     = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`
```

Nothing prevents `A` and `B` from being **the same type**. In that case, you'd be conflicting with the reflexive implementation of `From`: `impl<T> From<T> for T`.

See also:

- [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Not as ergonomic as it'd be in an ideal world but the explanation is reasonable. Would be a nice feature to have it work in the future.

Thanks!