# How can I implement the From trait for all types implementing a trait but use a specific implementation for certain types?

Tags: rust, traits

I am implementing the `std::convert::From` trait for a struct containing a `Cow<str>`. Is there a way to use the same implementation for all different kinds of integers (`u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `usize` and so on)?

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

pub struct Luhn<'a> {
    code: Cow<'a, str>,
}
```

I can easily implement code for all integers using a trait bound on the `ToString` trait, but then I cannot use a specific implementation for `str` and `String` - this way the benefits of `Cow` cannot be exploited. When I write specific implementations for `str` and `String`, I get a compile error:

> ```
> error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<&str>` for type `Luhn<'_>`:
>   --> src/lib.rs:23:1
>    |
> 7  | impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Luhn<'a> {
>    | ----------------------------------- first implementation here
> ...
> 23 | impl<'a, T: ToString> From<T> for Luhn<'a> {
>    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `Luhn<'_>`
> ```

I understand that this is due to the fact that Rust does not offer function overloading. How could this be solved in an elegant way?

```
impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Luhn<'a> {
    fn from(input: &'a str) -> Self {
        Luhn {
            code: Cow::Borrowed(input),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> From<String> for Luhn<'a> {
    fn from(input: String) -> Self {
        Luhn {
            code: Cow::Owned(input),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T: ToString> From<T> for Luhn<'a> {
    fn from(input: T) -> Self {
        Luhn {
            code: Cow::Owned(input.to_string()),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `&str` and `String` both implement `ToString`, you can use the unstable [*specialization*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/specialization.html) feature:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

use std::borrow::Cow;

pub struct Luhn<'a> {
    code: Cow<'a, str>,
}

impl<'a, T: ToString> From<T> for Luhn<'a> {
    default fn from(input: T) -> Self {
//  ^^^^^^^
        Luhn {
            code: Cow::Owned(input.to_string()),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a str> for Luhn<'a> {
    fn from(input: &'a str) -> Self {
        Luhn {
            code: Cow::Borrowed(input),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> From<String> for Luhn<'a> {
    fn from(input: String) -> Self {
        Luhn {
            code: Cow::Owned(input),
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, you cannot implement `Display` for `Luhn` because you'd run into [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423)

Comment: Thanks very much! Besides this unstable feature there is no way to make use of maybe some special Cow property? Or a specific trait.