# Implement Into for generic type where its component implements Into

Tags: rust

I have a type `IntPair<T>` which is generic over the type of some of its elements. The element type `T` may be some minimally restrictive type (`Int64`), or some more restrictive type which provides more guarantees (`Int32`, which in this case guarantees a reduced range of possible values).

The more restrictive element type implements `Into` the less restrictive element type. I want this conversion to generically carry into the type `IntPair<T>` which uses the other type as elements.

Here's an example:

```
pub struct Int32(pub i32);
pub struct Int64(pub i64);
impl Into<Int64> for Int32 {
    fn into(self) -> Int64 {
        Int64(self.0 as i64)
    }
}
pub struct IntPair<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
}
impl<T: Into<Int64>> Into<IntPair<Int64>> for IntPair<T> {
    fn into(self) -> IntPair<Int64> {
        IntPair {
            x: self.x.into(),
            y: self.y.into(),
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let p32: IntPair<Int32> = IntPair {
        x: Int32(3),
        y: Int32(9),
    };
    let p64: IntPair<Int64> = p32.into();
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work.

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::Into<IntPair<Int64>>` for type `IntPair<_>`:
  --> src/main.rs:12:1
   |
12 | impl<T: Into<Int64>> Into<IntPair<Int64>> for IntPair<T> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T, U> std::convert::Into<U> for T
             where U: std::convert::From<T>;
```

If I understand, the compiler cannot guarantee that there isn't an impl of `From<IntPair<T>> for IntPair<Int64>`, which would trigger a conflicting impl of `Into<IntPair<Int64>> for IntPair<T>`, due to `IntPair<T>` not being a concrete type.

That makes sense, but I would still like this feature. The only solution I can think of would be to create my own trait which behaves the same as `Into`. However, that would not be ideal, as the type would not work for methods that accept `impl Into<IntPair<Int64>>`.

Is there a way I can make this impl compile?

Comment: Implement `From` for the reverse direction, that's how it is supposed to work.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: I'm taking a look at it now.

Comment: @starblue your suggestion does not appear to work. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f5a326790f41ebb292a2a8f6f22d429c&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: @shepmaster you're welcome to mark this question as answered.

Comment: @Phoenix `From` from a type `T` to itself already exists for any `T`, so you are not allowed to redefine that for `IntPair<Int64>`. But `impl From<IntPair<Int32>> for IntPair<Int64>` should suffice for what you want to do.

Comment: @Starblue that doesn't really fit my goal. MCVE aside, there may be a large number of element types which implement `Into<Int64>`. I do not want to re-implement a conversion into `IntPair<Int64>` each time.