# How can I implement Borrow for a generic container in the case of the use of associated types?

Tags: rust

I would like to implement `Borrow` for `UserFriendlyDataStructure` to provide access to the `internal_data` field within a function that should be agnostic with respect to the data provider. The type of the `internal_data` field is determined by the type associated to trait `TraitA`. Note that the `Sealed` trait ensures that none of these traits here can be implemented by other crates; this is functionality that strictly I provide. Furthermore, the type `TraitA::Data` is restricted by the empty trait `DataTrait` to prevent `UserFriendlyDataStructure` from being used as that type.

The following example explains best:

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

mod private {
    pub trait Sealed {}
}

pub trait DataTrait: private::Sealed {}

pub trait TraitA: private::Sealed {
    type Data: DataTrait;
}

pub struct UserFriendlyDataStructure<A: TraitA> {
    internal_data: A::Data,
    _a: PhantomData<A>,
}

impl<A: TraitA> Borrow<A::Data> for UserFriendlyDataStructure<A> {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &A::Data {
        &self.internal_data
    }
}

pub fn important_function<A: TraitA, T: Borrow<A::Data>>(data: &T) {
    let _internal_data = data.borrow();
    // Do lots of work.
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    pub struct TestData(u32);

    impl super::private::Sealed for TestData {}

    impl DataTrait for TestData {}

    pub struct TestProvider;

    impl super::private::Sealed for TestProvider {}

    impl TraitA for TestProvider {
        type Data = TestData;
    }

    #[test]
    fn basic_test() {
        let ufds: UserFriendlyDataStructure<TestProvider> = UserFriendlyDataStructure {
            internal_data: TestData(100),
            _a: PhantomData::default(),
        };

        important_function::<TestProvider, _>(&ufds);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler complains:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::borrow::Borrow<UserFriendlyDataStructure<_>>` for type `UserFriendlyDataStructure<_>`:
  --> src/lib.rs:19:1
   |
19 | impl<A: TraitA> Borrow<A::Data> for UserFriendlyDataStructure<A> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> std::borrow::Borrow<T> for T
             where T: ?Sized;
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Is this the same as https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32315?

Comment: It does look like it's the same issue. I'm not too happy that it would require the use of specialization to solve though, since that's not stable yet. The alternatives I see is to write the implementations out by hand for all types that implement `TraitA` (which is not very flexible), or to use `AsRef` instead of `Borrow` (which is suboptimal for other reasons in my case).

Comment: Is there any reasonable trait bound you could apply to `Data`? If you can restrict it so it can't be `UserFriendlyDataStructure`, the error should be resolved.

Comment: `Data` really allows arbitrary types. Since I control which types implement `TypeA` (it's an internal trait that should never have external implementations), I can create an artificial trait bound to `Data` (e.g. an empty trait). I will try that and write an answer if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a trait bound to `Data` (via `TraitA`) didn't work. I can update the original question or add an answer with my attempt at solving it that way. What should I do?

Comment: Hm, then there seems to be another bug here. Since it didn't work, updating the question seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can be cajoled into accepting the code by introducing a redundant second type parameter that is constrained to be identical to `A::Data`:

```
impl<A, D> Borrow<D> for UserFriendlyDataStructure<A>
where
    A: TraitA<Data = D>,
    D: DataTrait,
{
    fn borrow(&self) -> &A::Data {
        &self.internal_data
    }
}
```

I don't know why this works, and simply constraining `A::Data: DataTrait` doesn't. I think the compiler should accept both versions.

([Full code on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=53b800ef074eb251e6964a6eada87018))

**Edit:** The fact that we need the redundant type `D` in the above code appears to be a [shortcoming of the current compiler implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50237), and is hopefully resolved once the experimental type inference engine [chalk](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/chalk) gets integrated in the compiler.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Do you think I should open an issue on the `rust` repository?

Comment: @Eleanore Probably.  Make sure to add a link to the issue phimuemue mentioned above.

Comment: *I don't know why this works* — because generics are considered "input" types and associated types are considered "output" types. ([When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/155423)). Multiple trait implementations can have the same output type so it's ambiguous. Placing it as an input type requires it to be unambiguous (because of coherence).

Comment: @Shepmaster I still don't really understand this.  If I only have a single type parameter `A: TraitA` and I add the bound `A::Data: DataTrait`, it is guaranteed that `A::Data` can't be `UserFriendlyDataStructure`, so there are no conflicting implementations. Why is the compiler complaining in this case? (I'm setting aside the fact that `A::Data` can't ever be `UserFriendlyDataStructure<A>` anyway, so there really isn't a conflict here in any case, but I can understand that the compiler can't see that.)

Comment: *it is guaranteed that `A::Data` can't be `UserFriendlyDataStructure`* — why not? Nothing prevents someone from implementing that. This question is basically a duplicate of [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423).

Comment: @Shepmaster The version with two type parameters only works when adding the additional `DataTrait` constraint, so it's clearly that constraint that makes the compiler think `D` can't be `UserFriendlyDataStructure`. If `UserFriendlyDataStructure` implemented the trait `DataTrait`, the compiler would now, since it would have to be in the current crate. If this constraint helps the compiler understand that `A::Data` can't be `UserFriendlyDataStructure` in one version, why doesn't the compiler understand this in the other version?

Comment: @Shepmaster If you are still interested, I've boiled the point I don't understand down to a minimal example: [version that compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=767c2ec35433903f08bf1ef63770ab57), [version that doesn't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=2ee279e043b119e49122f9fb239748d6). I've thoroughly read all the threads you linked, but I found no explanation for this behaviour, and I still think that the two versions should be equivalent.

Comment: @EleanoreY No need to report an issue for this – there already is one: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50237