# What does a closure prefixed with `static` mean? And when would I use it?

Tags: rust, static, closures

I stumbled across an example with `static || { }` in docs which works. Yet an attempt to use such an expression in my own code fails. I wonder why.

the very example from https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/macro.pin.html

```
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]
use std::{
    ops::{Generator, GeneratorState},
    pin::pin,
};

fn generator_fn() -> impl Generator<Yield = usize, Return = ()> /* not Unpin */ {
 // Allow generator to be self-referential (not `Unpin`)
 // vvvvvv        so that locals can cross yield points.
    static || {
        let foo = String::from("foo");
        let foo_ref = &foo; // ------+
        yield 0;                  // | <- crosses yield point!
        println!("{foo_ref}"); // <--+
        yield foo.len();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut generator = pin!(generator_fn());
    match generator.as_mut().resume(()) {
        GeneratorState::Yielded(0) => {},
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
    match generator.as_mut().resume(()) {
        GeneratorState::Yielded(3) => {},
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
    match generator.resume(()) {
        GeneratorState::Yielded(_) => unreachable!(),
        GeneratorState::Complete(()) => {},
    }
}
```

my attempt which fails:

```
fn func() -> impl Fn() {
    static || {
        println!("qwerty");
    }
}
```

with the following error:

```
error[E0697]: closures cannot be static
 --> ./ex_099.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     static || {
  |     ^^^^^^^^^
```

rust version:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.70.0-nightly (88fb1b922 2023-04-10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of writing, the Rust stable toolchain does not support static closures in any way. What you are seeing is the use of the unstable feature [**generators**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/generators.html), which resorts to a closure-like syntax to represent *generator functions*. Quoting a few relevant parts:

> A generator is a "resumable function" that syntactically resembles a closure but compiles to much different semantics in the compiler itself. [...] Generators use the `yield` keyword to "return", and then the caller can resume a generator to resume execution just after the yield keyword.
>
> [...]
>
> Generators are *closure-like* literals which can contain a `yield` statement. The `yield` statement takes an optional expression of a value to yield out of the generator. All generator literals implement the `Generator` trait in the `std::ops` module

As an unstable feature, any details about its functioning are subject to change. As of `nightly-2023-04-02`, the syntax `static || { /* ... */ }` will only work if you add the necessary feature attributes, make the function return `impl Generator` instead of `impl Fn`, and you include at least one `yield` in the generator.

```rust
#![feature(generators, generator_trait)]
use std::ops::Generator;

fn func() -> impl Generator<Yield = (), Return = ()> {
    static || {
        yield;
        println!("qwerty");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=801494f426bb0809632b5f83eef52853)

See also:

- [How to convert a closure without a yield to a generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755150/how-to-convert-a-closure-without-a-yield-to-a-generator)

Comment: Note that there are also generators without `static`, and the difference is that `static` generators are allowed to be self-referential and therefore don't implement `Unpin` while non-`static` generators are not allowed to be self-referential and therefore implement `Unpin`.