# Rust Error: The size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, rust, traits

first of all I want to mention that there many similar question on StackOverflow and around the web but I just can't figure out how to solve this error for my case.

So I have a struct, which represents my own error type:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Error {
    msg: String,
}
```

Then I continued implementing `Display` and `std::error::Error` for my error type:

```
impl Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.msg)
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for Error {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        &self.msg
    }
}
```

Now I tried to implement `std::convert::From` so I can use my error type  seamlessly with the `?` operator:

```
impl From<dyn std::error::Error> for Error {
    fn from(err: dyn std::error::Error) -> Self {
        Error {
            msg: err.to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

But then the rust-compiler gives me this error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)` cannot be known
at compilation time
  --> wasm_api/geohub_wasm_filehandler_api/src/lib.rs:33:6
   |
33 | impl From<dyn std::error::Error> for Error {
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
```

I know that by default, generic functions will work only on types that have a known size at compile time. But I cant figure out how to solve this problem properly.

Thanks for your help!

**Link to code on Rust-Playground:**

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=568900e8c7847c1f79781fa9bb6d499d

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean by "so I can use my error type seamlessly with the ? operator". This playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=92906e8ad7152b7bf3f1e51ecadceb23 seems to work as intended with regard to what you are attempting. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I basiclly need to convert the std::error::Error into my Error for use in another function, that returns a result with my own errortype - but inside the function i call functions that return the std::error::Error as part of their result

Comment: Note that without specialization (which hasn't been landed into stable yet, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844), you cannot convert "anything that implements Error" into `MyError`, because `MyError` implements `Error`, and Rust already has a blanket implementation for converting something into itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347311/how-is-there-a-conflicting-implementation-of-from-when-using-a-generic-type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @SirDarius says above, you can't do this for an `Error` because Error is not a type, it's a trait. (If you're coming from OOP, think of a Trait like an interface. You can't convert an interface into another type of object because the interface doesn't have any underlying state -- there's no "there" there.)

The right way to handle this is to implement From for each concrete type you need to support. [This video](https://youtu.be/YFzF1AHYjes?t=2755) really helped me understand how this all fits together.

Comment: As I look at this answer again, I realize it's probably worth pointing out that you CAN use a generic param here; this is how `anyhow` does it: https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/src/anyhow/error.rs.html#527-536. Of course, if you're going that route, you should probably consider just using `anyhow`.