# Implement From with multiple type parameters

Tags: rust, box

I was playing around the visitor design pattern in Rust. My initial visitor didn't have any type parameter so I was able to do something like this:

```
impl<T> From<T> for Box<dyn VisitorElement>
where
    T: VisitorElement + 'static,
{
    fn from(elem: T) -> Box<dyn VisitorElement> {
        Box::new(elem)
    }
}
```

As my visitor was simply a `f32` calculator, I wanted to make it more generic by replacing `f32` by a type parameter. After passing the proper type parameter everywhere, my `From` implementation wouldn't work. Here's a complete example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=213e822ad1874a8433885265dbc5416b)):

```
/*
 * Visitor traits
 */
trait Visitor<T> {
    fn visit_literal(&mut self, literal: &Literal<T>);
}

trait VisitorElement<T> {
    fn accept(&self, visitor: &mut dyn Visitor<T>);
}
/*
 * Literal value
 */
struct Literal<T> {
    value: T,
}
impl<T> Literal<T> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        Self { value: value }
    }
}
impl<T> VisitorElement<T> for Literal<T> {
    fn accept(&self, visitor: &mut dyn Visitor<T>) {
        visitor.visit_literal(self)
    }
}

impl<K, T> From<K> for Box<dyn VisitorElement<T>>
where
    K: VisitorElement<T> + 'static,
{
    fn from(elem: K) -> Box<dyn VisitorElement<T>> {
        Box::new(elem)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let element = Literal::new(0.1);
    let boxed: Box<dyn VisitorElement<_>> = element.into();
}
```

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<(dyn VisitorElement<_> + 'static)>>` for type `std::boxed::Box<(dyn VisitorElement<_> + 'static)>`:
  --> src/main.rs:28:1
   |
28 | / impl<K, T> From<K> for Box<dyn VisitorElement<T>>
29 | | where
30 | |     K: VisitorElement<T> + 'static,
31 | | {
...  |
34 | |     }
35 | | }
   | |_^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> std::convert::From<T> for T;
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `VisitorElement<_>` for type `std::boxed::Box<(dyn VisitorElement<_> + 'static)>`
```

My goal was to allow auto boxing dynamic types in order to make code typing less verbose.

From [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347311/how-is-there-a-conflicting-implementation-of-from-when-using-a-generic-type), I can see that the type `S` can cause the trait to convert to itself but in my case the type `K` is constrained to `VisitorElement` but I stille end up with a conflict with a `Box<dyn VisitorElement<_> + 'static>`.

Is there a reason why the constraint on `K: VisitorElement<T> + 'static` allows a `Box<dyn VisitorElement<T> + 'static>` into itself but `K: VisitorElement<f32>` doesn't?

From my understanding, the type `K` can't be a `Box` because `Box` doesn't implement `VisitorElement<T>`, so I should never end up with a Box as `K`.

If the issue was caused by the `Into` being automatically implemented... I'd have From> for `Literal<_>` then `Literal<_>` into `Box<dyn VisitorElement<_>`, but that's true for any type. In my case it doesn't explicitly do that, unless the `Box` is a special type that implements the same trait as its content?

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE], emphasis on the **minimal**. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @trentcl not sure what you mean. Initially it was just `VisitorElement` then I made `VisitorElement<T>` to pass a type parameter to allow for something else than f32. If the type is manually specified it works... but if it isn't it end up trying to convert to itself.

Comment: I edited the question. @Shepmaster I'm not sure it's the same issue as you linked or at least not as directly.

Comment: *because `Box` doesn't implement `VisitorElement<T>`* — this doesn't matter. From the proposed duplicate (emphasis mine): *someone **may** implement [...] so that the `From` impl you have written overlaps with the impl in the standard library*.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes but why doesn't From for `Box<dyn VisitorElement<f32>>` also overlap?

Comment: It **is** allowed (does not break the coherence rules) for a downstream crate to `struct Arg;  impl VisitorElement<Arg> for Box<dyn VisitorElement<Arg>> {...}`, which would cause a conflict with `From<T> for T`. It **is not** possible for a downstream crate to simply `impl VisitorElement<f32> for Box<dyn VisitorElement<f32>>`, because there are no local types in that `impl`. The interaction of coherence and generics is complex and subtle; I suggest reading [RFC #2451](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2451-re-rebalancing-coherence.md) for an introduction.

Comment: Are you *sure* that `VisitorElement` should be generic over `T`? Can you, for instance, usefully implement `VisitorElement<f32>` for `Literal<f64>`? If not, an associated type may be more correct. [Here's an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9db2bcce565c7950b68a5854d27333e5).