# Why doesn't Box<dyn Error> implement Error?

Tags: rust

Why doesn't `Box<dyn Error>` implement `Error`?

I am trying to use the `context()` method from `anyhow` on a `Result<surf::Response, surf::Error>`, and it's not cooperating:

```rust
let documents = surf::post("http://10.11.99.1/documents/")
    .await
    .map_err(Box::<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static>::from)
    .context("could not query device")?;
```

Even with this ugly cast, it still won't work, because `surf::Error` doesn't implement `Error`, and neither does `Box<dyn Error>`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Indeed it doesn't; which is highly surprising to people, including me when I originally learned of it:

```rust
fn impls_error<T: std::error::Error>() {}
impls_error::<Box<dyn std::error::Error>>();
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn std::error::Error` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
2 |     fn impls_error<T: std::error::Error>() {}
  |                       ----------------- required by this bound in `impls_error`
3 |     impls_error::<Box<dyn std::error::Error>>();
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn std::error::Error`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::error::Error` for `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`
```

The short rationale is listed in [the Rust issue tracking this (#60759)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/60759):

> Unfortunately, extending the `impl<T: Error> Error for Box<T>` to also apply for `T: ?Sized` fails because then the `impl<'a, E: Error + 'a> From<E> for Box<dyn Error + 'a>` starts overlapping with `impl<T> From<T> for T`.

The long rationale is that Rust [has this blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/std/error/trait.Error.html#impl-Error-35):

```rust
impl<T: Error> Error for Box<T> {}
```

This generic type has an implicit `Sized` bound, so it could be equivalently written as:

```rust
impl<T: Error + Sized> Error for Box<T> {}
```

If you try to apply this implementation to `Box<dyn Error>`, then `T` would need to equal `dyn Error`. The compiler disallows that because `dyn Error` by itself is *unsized*.

The next step you'd take to fix this would be to loosen the bound to allow `?Sized` types:

```rust
impl<T: Error + ?Sized> Error for Box<T> {}
```

However, if you do this, then you'll end up with conflicting implementations of the `From` trait's [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3CT%3E-12) and the [conversion of an concrete error to a `Box<dyn Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E):

```rust
impl<T> From<T> for T {} // #1

impl<'a, E: Error + 'a> From<E> for Box<dyn Error + 'a> {} // #2
```

**If** we could have both of these implementations in play at the same time, then it would become ambiguous what should happen for this code:

```rust
let a: Box<dyn Error> = todo!();
let b: Box<dyn Error> = a.into();
```

Should it leave it as is (following impl *1*) or box it *again* (following impl *2*)? Chances are that most people would want *1*, but both paths are valid. That's the long form answer as to why `Box<dyn Error>` cannot implement `Error` itself at this point in time.

In the future, specialization might allow for both of these to overlap and pick a specific case (probably *1*, I'd guess).

See also:

- [How is there a conflicting implementation of `From` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423)

---

SNAFU, my competitor to anyhow, also [faced the same problem](https://github.com/shepmaster/snafu/issues/76). There, we introduced [a trait to help work around the issue](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.6.10/snafu/trait.AsErrorSource.html). It might be easiest to see what the `Snafu` macro expands to (cleaned up a bit):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
struct Demo {
    source: Box<dyn std::error::Error>,
}
```

becomes

```rust
impl Error for Demo {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)> {
        use snafu::AsErrorSource;
        match *self {
            Self { ref source, .. } => Some(source.as_error_source()),
        }
    }
}
```

This way, we don't need to rely on `source` actually implementing `Error` itself, but instead have a number of concrete implementations that don't overlap with the blanket implementation:

```rust
impl AsErrorSource for dyn Error + 'static
impl AsErrorSource for dyn Error + Send + 'static
impl AsErrorSource for dyn Error + Sync + 'static
impl AsErrorSource for dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static
impl<T: Error + 'static> AsErrorSource for T
```

95% of the credit for this solution goes to [kennytm](https://github.com/kennytm), who helped me immeasurably by figuring out that trick!