# Miette - How to specify errors that contain a generic that defaults to Box<dyn Error>?

Tags: rust

While this question is about the miette library, it could probably be answered by every experienced Rustacean by looking at the [miette sourcecode](https://github.com/zkat/miette). It isn't that big, but I wasn't able to extract the answer from it, sadly.

All the following examples assume the dependencies:

```
miette = { version = "4.4", features = ["fancy"] }
thiserror = "1.0"
```

I currently have a custom error definition similar to the following in my library [tokio-graceful-shutdown](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-graceful-shutdown):

```
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error, miette::Diagnostic)]
pub enum MyError {
    #[error("Error containing another error")]
    AnError(#[source] Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>),
}
```

**I would like the source error type to be generic, with a default value of `Box<dyn Error>`.**

---

### *My attempts*

If I would leave out the `miette::Diagnostic`, the solution would look like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error)]
pub enum MyError<ErrType = Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
    #[error("Error containing another error")]
    AnError(#[source] ErrType),
}
```

If I would leave out the `Box<dyn Error>` default value, the solution would look like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error, miette::Diagnostic)]
pub enum MyError<ErrType: 'static + Error> {
    #[error("Error containing another error")]
    AnError(#[source] ErrType),
}
```

Sadly, combining the two, it turns out that `Box<dyn Error>` does NOT implement `Error`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error, miette::Diagnostic)]
pub enum MyError<ErrType: 'static + Error = Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
    #[error("Error containing another error")]
    AnError(#[source] ErrType),
}
```

```
|
| pub enum MyError<ErrType: 'static + Error = Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
|                                     ^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
|
= help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)`
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::error::Error` for `Box<(dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync + 'static)>`
```

I suspect, however, that this error message is a red herring and instead, the `'static + Error` is incorrect and `ErrType` needs a different restriction.

The reason why I suspect this is that if I directly use `Box<dyn Error>` as the source type, it works, as in the first example. That makes me believe that it isn't actually `Error` that `miette::Diagnostic` requires to work.

---

### *Final question*

(which is hopefully not susceptible to the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

What should be inserted at the `<???>` placeholder to make the following code compile?

```rust
#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error, miette::Diagnostic)]
pub enum MyError<ErrType: <???> = Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>> {
    #[error("Error containing another error")]
    AnError(#[source] ErrType),
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For why this happens, see [Why doesn't Box<dyn Error> implement Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151237/why-doesnt-boxdyn-error-implement-error) (by the way, this is not related to miette at all: [the error is triggered even without it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d96c266dcf6c4d5661b24c0abf0f8caa)).

You can use a newtype wrapper to work around this problem:

```rust
pub struct BoxedError(pub Box<dyn Error + Send + Sync>);

impl fmt::Debug for BoxedError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Debug::fmt(&self.0, f)
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for BoxedError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Display::fmt(&self.0, f)
    }
}

impl Error for BoxedError {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)> {
        self.0.source()
    }
    #[allow(deprecated)]
    fn description(&self) -> Option<&str> {
        self.0.description()
    }
    #[allow(deprecated)]
    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&dyn Error> {
        self.0.cause()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, thiserror::Error, miette::Diagnostic)]
pub enum MyError<ErrType: 'static + Error = BoxedError> {
    #[error("Error containing another error")]
    AnError(#[source] ErrType),
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)
The question though is, why did my original verison work? The one that used `Box<dyn Error>` directly in the `#[source]` tag? As `Box<dyn Error>` does not implement `Error` and, to my knowledge, template specialization is not a thing in Rust?

Comment: @Finomnis `thiserror` uses the same trick @Shepmaster talks about in his answer, in the linked question.

Comment: Aaaaah, I see. That makes a lot of sense now, very smart of them. I will have to think about your code, but it might actually give me what I need. Thanks :)

Comment: Turns out you are right, the fact that `#[source]` accepted `Box<dyn Error>` in the first place is in [this](https://github.com/dtolnay/thiserror/blob/master/src/aserror.rs) little piece of magic, it's not even part of miette at all.