# Why does the decorator pattern work for owned types, but causes a trait evaluation overflow (E0275) for references?

Tags: recursion, rust, decorator, traits

While experimenting with the decorator design pattern in Rust, I came across what I believe may be a compiler error, but I am too new to the language to be confident.

I think that the following example code should not generate a recursive trait [E0275](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0275) error.

A simple type that can be converted to an `i64`:

```rust
enum MyNumbers {
    Zero,
    One,
    Two,
}

impl From<MyNumbers> for i64 {
    fn from(n: MyNumbers) -> Self {
        match n {
            MyNumbers::Zero => 0,
            MyNumbers::One => 1,
            MyNumbers::Two => 2,
        }
    }
}
```

And here, a struct that might be used in a decorator:

```rust
struct MyWrapper<N> {
    n: N,
}
```

`MyWrapper<N>` can be converted to an `i64` if `N` can be converted to `i64`.

```rust
impl<N> From<MyWrapper<N>> for i64
where
    N: Into<i64>,
{
    fn from(wrapper: MyWrapper<N>) -> Self {
        wrapper.n.into()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b1893633d2f01fed779c5923d3043ab)

This works as I expect.

Now I want to be able to construct an `i64` from `MyWrapper` without consuming it. I change my `From` trait implementations to operate on references:

```rust
impl From<&MyNumbers> for i64 {
    fn from(n: &MyNumbers) -> Self {
        match n {
            MyNumbers::Zero => 0,
            MyNumbers::One => 1,
            MyNumbers::Two => 2,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, N> From<&'a MyWrapper<N>> for i64
where
    &'a N: Into<i64>,
{
    fn from(wrapper: &'a MyWrapper<N>) -> Self {
        (&wrapper.n).into()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba1c488664ba85e221e81cc47acb951e)

But now...

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `i64: From<&MyWrapper<_>>`
  --> src/main.rs:34:13
   |
34 |     let i = i64::from(&w);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="256"]` attribute to your crate (`playground`)
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<i64>` for `&MyWrapper<_>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `From<&MyWrapper<MyWrapper<_>>>` for `i64`
   = note: 126 redundant requirements hidden
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `From<&MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<MyWrapper<_>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>` for `i64`
```

Why was this fine for owned types, but not references?

Also, this really confuses me -
No calls to `i64::from()` is fine - [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ed74ddc542ef0dbee2b2b4816dcff77)
Call to different `i64::from` errors - but should not be evaluating my code!? [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6035062686b35aa5b739f5add60a8166)

```rust
fn main() {
    i64::from(32i32);
}
```

Comment: [Another error in a similar area](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37347311/155423)

Comment: Thanks @kmdreko. Yes! This is in fact a known 5 year old compiler bug. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler bug. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37748

As a workaround, I have had to resort to #[derive(Copy)] to prevent my types from being consumed at each level of the conversion.  Perhaps From/Into is poorly suited to this pattern.... Until the language matures a little more.