# Use From to convert the inner value of a parametric type

Tags: rust

If I have a parametric type like this:

```
struct Outer<A> {
   inner: A,
}
```

Is it possible to create an implementation of the `From` trait for `Outer` that will convert `Outer<A>` to `Outer<B>` if there exists a `From` that converts `A` to `B`?

Something like this (which doesn't work, as far as I can tell):

```
impl<A, B: From<A>> From<Outer<A>> for Outer<B> {
    fn from(oa: Outer<A>) -> Self {
        Outer {
            inner: oa.inner.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is (currently) possible, because there's nothing to stop `A` and `B` being the same (which gives rise to a conflict with the blanket reflexive implementation provided by the standard library).  Instead, consider providing an inherent conversion method; or perhaps your own `From` trait?

Comment: @eggyal I don't believe I know what "an inherent conversion method" is?

Comment: "Inherent" just means an `impl` directly on the type (i.e. not of a trait).  So something like `impl<A> Outer<A> { fn convert<B>(self) -> Outer<B> where A: Into<B> { Outer { inner: self.inner.into() } } }` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is there a conflicting implementation of \`From\` when using a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347311/how-is-there-a-conflicting-implementation-of-from-when-using-a-generic-type)