# How can I implement generic conversion from my type to any type with a bound?

Tags: rust, traits, orphan-rule

I am trying to implement the conversion from my type to any type that can be converted from u32.

I tried `impl<T> From<MyType> for T where u32: Into<T>` by that apparently breaks the orphan rule. As well as `impl<T> Into<T> for MyType where u32: Into<T>` but that leads to [a conflicting implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347311/how-is-there-a-conflicting-implementation-of-from-when-using-a-generic-type?noredirect=1&lq=1). Can I achieve what I want for From / Into?

```rust
pub enum MyType {
    Case0,
    Case1,
    Case2
}

fn conv<T>(s: MyType) -> T
    where u32: Into<T> {
    match s {
        MyType::Case0 => 0.into(),
        MyType::Case1 => 1.into(),
        MyType::Case2 => 2.into(),
    }
}

impl From<MyType> for u32 {
    fn from(s: MyType) -> Self {
        conv::<Self>(s)
    }   
}

impl From<MyType> for u64 {
    fn from(s: MyType) -> Self {
        conv::<Self>(s)
    }   
}
```

(Yes, I know I can use C-like enums but that's not the topic of this question)

Comment: Macros? Custom trait? A conversion function?

Comment: I'd like to have the Into / From traits automatically ;D A conversion function is basically what I wrote there. And I guess a macro would allow me to do it for all the types I can think of but not other ones?

Comment: Yes regarding the macro. I don't think you can use `From`/`Into`.

Comment: Probably helpful: [Transitive From/Into - why, and why not? (r/rust)](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/cdmopy/transitive_frominto_why_and_why_not/)