Rust into implementation conflict core
I have a Result like enum:
enum Choice<A, B> {
    A(A),
    B(B),
} 

I wanted this type to implement Into if both generics are T.
Attempt 1:
impl<T> Into<T> for Choice<T, T> {
    fn into(self) -> T {
        let (Choice::A(x) | Choice::B(x)) = self;
        x
    }
}

Gets me:
conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
            - impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
              where U: From<T>;

Attempt 2:
impl<T> From<Choice<T, T>> for T {
    fn from(x: Choice<T, T>) -> Self {
        let (Choice::A(x) | Choice::B(x)) = x;
        x
    }
}

Gets me:
implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types  
for which it is implemented is local, and no uncovered type parameters  
appear before that first local type

Edit: i understand both these errors i am just trying to find out if there is another way to get Into implemented.

Side note: You might be interested in Either.

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347311/how-is-there-a-conflicting-implementation-of-from-when-using-a-generic-type


Edit: i understand both these errors i am just trying to find out if there is another way to get Into implemented.

No, you can't. This might change in the future. The only working scenario is to use types where the compiler knows that From<Choice<..>> is not implemented. This would work:
impl Into<i32> for Choice<i32, i32> {
    fn into(self) -> i32 { todo!() }
}

Here, i32 does not implement From<Choice<..>>. Using any other type that implements From (or could implement, like generic types) results in a conflict with the blanket implementation by std::core.
The following, non-generic implementation for Into, fails to compile for the same reason:
struct Other;

impl<T> From<Choice<T, T>> for Other {
    fn from(_value: Choice<T, T>) -> Self { todo!() }
}

impl Into<Other> for Choice<Other, Other> {
    fn into(self) -> Other { todo!() }
}


The reason the second attempt doesn't work is because some other crate might write something like the following, which might conflict with your impl.
struct Foo;

impl<T: Debug> From<T> for Foo { .... }

Rust had to tiebreak and allow only one of the two conflicting trait implementations. And unfortunately it chose to disallow yours.

For the first attempt, as the note mentioned, The Into implementation for T defined in Rust core contains all types such as your trait Choice, so there is implementation conflict when you want to implement it for your trait again.
conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
            - impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
              where U: From<T>;

For the second attempt, I think the error note was explained enough.
If you don't want to use Either for some reason. you can use the follows implementation. which remove the Into trait.
impl<T> Choice<T, T> {
    fn into(self) -> T {
        let (Choice::A(x) | Choice::B(x)) = self;
        x
    }
}


U didn't explicitly say but is there no other work around way for my type Choice to implement Into?
